# Map bean fields to CSV in the order they appear in the class

Tags: java

I would like to map every field in a given bean to a CSV in the same order as they are declared in the class definition.

The only thing I have considered so far is using `.class.getDeclaredFields()` because it returns them in the correct order, and then mapping them using something like OpenCSV.

Is there any quicker way to do this?

Comment: I don't recommend you to rely on field order. Rather make the first line of the CSV for the headers (field names), then you can map each column to a field.

Comment: BTW, otherwise I would do it in the same way (with reflection). You have to take care of the type conversion as well.